# DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<KeyValuePair<int, string>>("exec mySproc") not mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I can't figure out why this works

```
var blah = this.Database.SqlQuery<MyObjectWithTwoStringPropsNamedKeyAndValue>("exec mySproc").ToList();
```

and this doesn't

```
var blah = this.Database.SqlQuery<KeyValuePair<string,string>>("exec mySproc").ToList();
```

"mySproc" returns three records with two varchar columns aliased "Key" and "Value".

In the second line of code, I get a list of three KeyValuePairs, but both properties (Key and Value) are null for each item in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `KeyValuePair` properties, `Key` and `Value` are readonly properties.

The values for `Key` and `Value` can only be set in the constructor, and not changed later.

[SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx) tries to map the columns returned by the stored procedure, but cannot find properties in which to write them. The documentation doesn't state that the properties must be writeable, but it's clear that it won't use the parameterized constructor, but the properties.

> The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query, or can be a simple primitive type.